# Looking to round the final answer to 2 decimals C++

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm trying to round my final answer to 2 decimals so it is Dollars and Cents.  I'm new to coding, and can't figure it out. I want to round "w" in the line that says "The amount you need to charge is"  Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Choice;


    float x, w;

    cout << "Please enter the amount needed." << endl;
    cin >> x;


    w = x/(1-0.0275);   

    cout << "The amount you need to charge is $"<< w << "." << endl;

    return (0);

}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/3600/ ?

Comment: You can't express most decimals exactly with floats. Use integers and calculate using pennies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the example here http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/3600/
You could use

```
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << w << endl;
```

(`fixed` is optional)

You will have to `#include <iomanip>`

As pointed out by Synxis, this will only work for printing the value, it will not change the value held by `w`

Comment: Correct for printing only. If he want 'w' to have only two decimals, he needs to round it ( int(100 * w)/100.0 ).

Comment: That's true, but I figured this is what he needed

Comment: Makes sense since the line is right before the return statement.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks! Added this to the code here: https://compilr.com/timbogrocott/square/Square.cpp

Answer (score 2):

You can alway multiply your answer `x` by 100, round, and then divide by 100.

```
x = (int)(x*100+0.5f);  
x = ( (float)(x) ) / 100.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your monetary unit to "cents" and then divide by 100 to get the dollars and mod 100 to get the cents.

```
unsigned int money = 152; // USD $1.52

cout << "Money is: " << (money / 100) << "." << (money % 100) << "\n";
```

This may be more accurate.  Search the web for "everything knows floating point".