# How do I get numbers in my ouput to display less place holders?

Tags: c++, decimal

I am very much a beginner programmer, finishing up Chapter 2 in Starting out with C++ (e7) by Tony Gladdis.  I am doing my best to teach myself.  Currently I am working on the Challenges at the end of the chapter.  The problem I am having is how my output is displaying.  With my current code, my output displays my numbers as 54.6293, when I just want it to display 54.62.  Can someone please tell me how I can specify in my code to create my desired output?

/* Write a program that computes the tax and tip on a restraunt bill for a patron with a 
$44.50 meal charge.  The tax should be 6.75 percent of the meal cost.  The tip should be
15 percent of the total after adding the tax.  Display the meal cost, tax amount, 
tip amount, and total bill on the screen*/

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        double Meal_Cost = 44.50,
            Total_After_Tax, Tax_Amount, Total_Bill, Total_Tip;
        const double TIP = 0.15,
            MEAL_TAX = 0.0675;

        // Calculate Tax_Amount
        Tax_Amount = Meal_Cost * MEAL_TAX;

        // Calculate Total_After_Tax
        Total_After_Tax = Tax_Amount + Meal_Cost;

        // Calculate Total_Tip
        Total_Tip = Total_After_Tax * TIP;

        // Calculate Total_Bill
        Total_Bill = Total_After_Tax + Total_Tip;

        // Display results
        cout << "The meal cost " << Meal_Cost << " dollars." << endl;
        cout << "The tax applied to the meal purchase was " << Tax_Amount << " dollars." << endl;
        cout << "The tip amount for the purchase was " << Total_Tip << " dollars." << endl;
        cout << "The total bill came to " << Total_Bill << " dollars." << endl;

        system ("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Use io manipulators like `setprecision()` etc. to control formatting.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - remember to `#include <iomanip>`

Comment: @Joe Remind the OP, not me. But THX anyway ;) ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do:

```
#include <iomanip>

...

cout << "The total bill came to " << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed 
     << Total_Bill << " dollars." << endl;
```

**Note:** When not using `std::fixed`, precision refers to the total amount of digits displayed. For example, `55`. When using `std::fixed`, precision refers to the amount of digits displayed *after* the decimal point. For example, `54.63`.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189084/looking-to-round-the-final-answer-to-2-decimals-c) for more details.